# Can I use row locks on rows that have not been created yet?

Tags: postgresql

Currently I am using Postgres' `advisory locks`, specifically `pg_advisory_xact_lock`, to lock IDs before I create rows with them in a transaction, so that they cannot be created in another transaction. The IDs are provided externally, so this can (and does) happen.

I am aware of row level locks, but my understanding is that they only work on rows with IDs that exist already. Is that correct? Or can I use row level locks on IDs which don't exist yet? If that makes sense...

Comment: Yes, a row that doesn't exist, can not be locked.

Comment: "The IDs are provided externally, so this can (and does) happen"  Why is the external agent not responsible for behaving itself?

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to do this is to put a unique or primary key constraint on the column. Then one of the inserting transactions will receive an error that it can handle.

If you want to mask that error, you could write a simple PL/pgSQL function that catches the error.  Or perhaps `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` can solve the underlying problem.

Comment: Thanks. That is how it first was. But I would like to avoid the duplicate key constraint error. That's why I introduced the advisory lock, which let's me handle if the row exists or not on the application layer...

Comment: @eikes you can use ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING, then no error is thrown.  You would check to see if 1 or 0 row was inserted to know if you succeeded or not.  But what is wrong with just teaching the application layer to handle errors?

Answer (score 0):

An inserted row is automatically locked.  But, how does this help you?  What do you want to do with the locked rows?