# MySQL IF Statement Race Condition

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

For simplicity, say there are two tables `A` and `B`, with unique indexes on non-key INT columns `COLUMN_A` and `COLUMN_B` respectively. I would like to do something like the following pseudo-SQL. (Note that this *would* be in a stored procedure but, according to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/lock-tables/, that's not allowed.)

```
IF COLUMN_A != x for all rows of A
   Single query to insert a row into B with COLUMN_B = x (if not exist)
```

The problem is that other parts of the code could read `A` and `B`, see that `x` does not exist in either, and try to insert `x` into `A` between the `IF` statement and insertion query. The race condition seems to necessitate a read/write lock on `A`. I don't think that InnoDB's internal locking would prevent this from happening (i.e. any locks used during the `IF` statement would be released before the execution of the insertion).

Crucially, COLUMN_A and COLUMN_B are formally unrelated so there doesn't appear to be a straightforward way to enforce a uniqueness constraint between them (given that a view involving both A and B probably wouldn't be updatable). (I would be fine creating some sort of "relationship" between them as long as they remain in separate tables but I'm not sure if there is anything that would do this.) Is it necessary to have a table lock on A in this case?

Something like this would seem like a better solution: [Can I use row locks on rows that have not been created yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71667586/can-i-use-row-locks-on-rows-that-have-not-been-created-yet) But this question is about Postgres and the features don't appear to be available in MySQL.

Thank you.

Comment: Include the condition on table `A` as a criteria of the query and do away with the if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the condition into the `INSERT` statement rather than using the `IF` statement.

```
INSERT INTO B (col1, col2, col3, ...)
SELECT val1, val2, val3, ...
FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM A
    WHERE column_a = 'x'
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Didn't realize this was possible.

Comment: Quick follow-up question: is there any neat way of determining which WHERE clause fails? For example, if `WHERE column_a = 'x'` becomes `WHERE column_a1 = 'x' OR column_a2 = 'x'`. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so, since you're not putting anything into the DB when any of them match, so there's no place to put that.

Comment: This also works for columns without unique index. :)